# Two identical iphones, one returns exc_bad_access on AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDualCamera

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios10, exc-bad-access, avcapturedevice

First question ever on Stack Overflow! This site has helped me with coding and technical problems for years. I've always found every answer here and never had to sign up and ask anything! But this one... I just don't get it!?

I'm building an ios app that's ios 10 compliant and compatible with the iPhone 7 dual camera. Now when initiating the AVCaptureDevice with this code:

```
AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDualCamera
                                                mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                position: preferredPosition];  
if(videoDevice == nil){
          videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera
                                                           mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                           position: preferredPosition];
     }
```

Very simple, if no AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDualCamera than AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera.

On one iPhone 6s 64gb (ios 10.2) it works like a charm! But when testing on an identical iPhone 6s 64gb (ios 10.2), that device returns EXC_BAD_ACCESS on line:

```
AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDualCamera
                                                mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                position: preferredPosition];
```

On that device, it only works if I completely remove the dual camera and set everything to wide angle. It should just return nil and switch to wide angle! What can be the problem... Zombie processes doesn't return anything useful. My guess is the second iPhone is just buggy. What do you guys think?

Comment: What about the camera permissions for this app.  Is it possible on the second phone the app is not permitted to access the camera?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. Checked the permissions manually, they were good, still no luck. Then I removed the app, re-installed, accepted all permissions and still no luck. Then changed everything to wide angle instead of dual camera and it did work. So the permissions for camera usage are good.

Comment: Did you try to use a 3rd party or Apple application supporting the `AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDualCamera` feature on the "problem device"?

Comment: Yes, afaik the Instagram and the native camera app both support AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDualCamera on ios 10 and they both work fine.

Comment: Tested your code.  Didn't crash with or without permission.  If possible post more info about the crash.  Maybe a stack trace.

Comment: Too bad I don't have the "problem-device" at my disposal. I also don't have any more information on the crash. Just EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the first moment of trying to access the dual camera. We'll try to do a total reset of that device next time. As it works like a charm on t=other devices, I'm still guessing it's a device issue.

Answer (score 1):

this is very odd, had the exact same issue and changing

```
AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDualCamera
```

to

```
AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDuoCamera
```

solved the issue... but what is strange, that the Duo is deprecated and dual should be used

```
AVF_EXPORT AVCaptureDeviceType const AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDuoCamera NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(10_0, 10_2, "Use AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDualCamera instead") __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and below solution worked for me.

Please try adding following flag in info.plist,
"Privacy - Camera Usage Description" and set any string value to it.
Save and Run the app.

Also if you want to use photo library, add "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" key and set any string value that you want to display in permission pop up.

Comment: All Usage Description are in place. Otherwise it also wouldn't have run on the other phone. So that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
In my case, in one device the cameras were not working! 
I went to the camera app and tried to use the camera, didn't work.
Restarted the device, cameras still don't work.
In this case `AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithDeviceType:AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDualCamera mediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo position:AVCaptureDevicePositionUnspecified];` just returns nil;

I took another device in which the cameras work ok. Now the very same line in code crashes.